# FCN with variable input and output size

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have to design a FCN which takes inputs with variable sizes (this is not a problem) but also the output has to vary. In particular, I have RxCx3 RGB input images and I want the output to be (R+C)x3. For instance, a 1024x2048x3 image should return an output of (1024+2048)x3=3072x3. The same has to be true with all the training image, the next batch could contain, for example, a 300x200x3 image so output should be 500x3.

I'm able to design FCNs which returns output of the same dimension of the input (as in the case of image segmentation) even if this one varies but I can't do the thing above...

Comment: What does your architecture look like when you output a same size image?